# Creating function wrappers

Tags: function, wrapper

I know there are a lot of questions/answers about function wrappers.
Let me add mine.

I have the situation that I have a function, let's call it `draw_this($arg1, $arg2)` that is being called in, let's say 38 different locations.

As it turned out later, draw_this() only works properly if we add `$arg3` as well. So draw_this() now looks like: `draw_this($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)`.

However `$arg3` has to be ALWAYS provided. To make the long story a bit shorter, a possible, yet in my opinion rather bad solution would be to create a wrapper function,
"Approach 1":

```
function draw_this_wrapper($arg1, $arg2){
   $arg3 = include($arg3);
   draw_this($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
}
```

or, even worse, "Approach 2":

```
draw_this($arg1, $arg2){
   $arg3 = include($arg3);
   ...
}
```

Why I really dislike those solutions is that they (at least in my opinion) destroy the principle of encapsulation which has too many advantages to get rid of (or am I wrong here as the information has to be provided every single time?). Approach 1 at least 'kinda' keeps the encapsulation. However it removes the ability to see what `draw_this()` really looks like (as it is called with three instead of just the two arguments.

However, I have the impression I might miss a design principle here, something that I do not know yet on how to properly solve this situation in a good/"clean" way. Can you give me an insight what would be a good solution here? (The main problem is that the function has to be changed at all 38 locations etc.).

Thanks in advance!!

p.s. Sorry, I forgot to add that `$arg3` is ALWAYS the same. So it does not change depending on the context. However, everything is done in a procedural environment. Solution? :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As I am working in a procedural environment I actually decided to go for "Approach 2". If any major problems occur I might report them here.